# Error uploading CSV from S3 to AWS Lambda: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, boto3

I'm attempting to just upload a csv from S3 into Lambda for simple processing, but am getting " "errorMessage": "'module' object is not callable",".

I'm using Python3.8 and here is the simple Lambda function:

```
import boto3
s3_client = boto3("s3")
def readindata(event, context):
    bucket_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    s3_file_name =  event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    resp = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name,Key=s3_file_name)
    data = resp['Body'].read().decode("utf-8")
    print(data)
```

I used serverless and CloudFormation for this, but the Yaml file is pretty simple as well:

```
service: readincsvdata2
# app and org for use with dashboard.serverless.com
#app: your-app-name
#org: your-org-name

# You can pin your service to only deploy with a specific Serverless version
# Check out our docs for more details
# frameworkVersion: "=X.X.X"

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.8
  region: us-east-1
  profile: serverless-admin
  timeout: 10
  memorySize: 128
  iamRoleStatements:
   - Effect: "Allow"
     Action:
       - "s3:*"
     Resource: "*"


custom:
  bucket: prototypeuploadcsv-08-13-2020v2
  pythonRequirements:
   dockerizePip: true

functions:
  protomodel-readcsv:
    handler: handler.readindata
    events:
      - s3:
          bucket: ${self:custom.bucket}
          event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
```

And I keep getting this **error:**

```
Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "'module' object is not callable",
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/imp.py\", line 234, in load_module\n    return load_source(name, filename, file)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/imp.py\", line 171, in load_source\n    module = _load(spec)\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 702, in _load\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 671, in _load_unlocked\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>\", line 783, in exec_module\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/handler.py\", line 3, in <module>\n    s3_client = boto3(\"s3\")\n"
  ]
}

Request ID:
```

It seems like I'm calling in or instantiating an object wrong, but I don't see it. I'm just using a super simple test csv as test data. Not sure what needs to be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably due to the following typo.

```
s3_client = boto3("s3")
```

should be

```
s3_client = boto3.client("s3")
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
s3_client = boto3("s3")
```

there should be:

```
s3_client = boto3.client("s3")
```